# No display on a asus laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard

There is no display on an Asus laptop, on its screen or via the HDMI port. Asus support tells me that it should due to a failed graphic card.

The graphic chipset is an Intel HD Graphics 3000 but I do not know if it is integrated with the CPU.

As you can see, there is two main chips on the board, but from [Intel website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/fr/fr/ark/products/52220/intel-core-i3-2310m-processor-3m-cache-2-10-ghz.html) the graphic module seems to be integrated to the CPU.

[image]

So, is it repairable ?

Answer (score 0):

Intel HD Graphics 3000 is a part of the CPU, so it's not repairable, short of replacing the motherboard or the Intel processor.